# Alt+tab multi displays

Tags: display, external-monitor, application-switcher

I'm Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome Shell on a HP Pavilion dm4 with an external display.

When I try to switch between applications using the Alt+tab shortcut, the box showing the applications is showed only on the laptop's display.

There's a way to make the box appear in **both** displays?